# How to remove indexes from array, only leaving values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, key, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have this array that's logged like so:

[image]

How can I "convert" the array to be simpler, so it outputs like this?
`["Acura", "Aston Martin", ...]`

Thanks!

Comment: um, that is just how the console shows it.

Comment: Yeap, the array does console like you want, but when you console.log it then it will show the index for convince purposes. Use document.write(myArray); if you wanna see for yourself :)

Comment: It's not an object, it's an array. So, no problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```js
console.log(["Acura", "Aston Martin"]);
```

Do this:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(["Acura", "Aston Martin"]));
```